# Como fazer o lightbox aparecer na frente de tudo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu uso o *Banner do Ebit* para os clientes poderem avaliar a compra no site, porém o **lightbox** dele sempre aparece atrás de todos os elementos da página.
Como fazer para que ele apareça na frente de tudo?

**O código abaixo é uma versão resumida do necessário para o banner carregar.**

```
<a id="bannerEbit"></a> <!-- Aqui ele carrega o banner com o background "banner.gif" do próprio Ebit -->

<script id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?storeId&lightbox=true"></script> <!-- Script do ebit de onde vêm as informações e o lightbox -->
```

como QUASE deve ser (só para verem o lightbox nesse exemplo sem o background)
[image: Exemplo de como QUASE deve ser (só para verem o lightbox)]

como está (Reparem que ainda aparece a sombra atrás, ou seja, o lightbox está carregando atrás de tudo)
[image: como está]

Comment: Tentou configurar o z-index?

Comment: como configurar o z-index tendo um script externo chamando uma variável?

Comment: o Z-index é uma classe CSS que controla o "eixo Z" dos elementos. Resumindo ele traz um elemento para frente do outro, desde que o elemento também tenha um "position" setado. O z-index quanto maior, mais o Elemento vem para frente dos outros. Qui vc pode ler a respeito https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode carregar o script por JavaScript (não jQuery) usando `create.Element` e depois detectar quando o script foi carregado na página, com isso você pode forçar o `z-index` os elementos do eBit com `.onload`.

Os elementos (fundo e o box) do eBit são duas `ids`: `#dark` e `#boxLight` respectivamente. Então faça assim:

```
var s = document.createElement("script"); 
s.src = "https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?storeId&lightbox=true"; 
s.id = "getSelo"; 
document.body.appendChild(s);

s.onload = function(){
   $("#dark, #boxLight").css('z-index','99999999');   
}
```

> Não esqueça de colocar o seu **storeId** na URL.

Comment: então não funciona com aquele jQuery?

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa não irá funcionar não.

Comment: não porque não existe a variável s

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Pode ser que funcione com jQuery, se adicionar um setTimeout

Comment: pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa `setTimeout(function(){ $("#dark, #boxLight").css('z-index','99999999') },1000);`

Comment: funcionou com JavaScript obrigado

Comment: Como você sabe quais são os ids do ebit?

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Basta olhar no código da página.